Using ranges::transform to write to uninitialized memory for trivial types
I have a question regarding using std::ranges::transform to write data into uninitialized memory. Consider full example: https://godbolt.org/z/WbzzY9qY5
TLDR: Is the following code valid?
auto copy_to_uninitialized_memory(const std::vector<Point> &data)
{
    // make_unique_for_overwrite "default initializes" array values
    auto buffer = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<Point[]>(data.size());

    auto multipleBy2 = [](const Point& input){
        return Point{input.x*2, input.y*2, input.z*2};
    };
    // Is following transform okay?
    std::ranges::transform(data, buffer.get(), multipleBy2);
    return buffer;
}

Using std::back_inserter with std::vector is well defined because vector::push_back mostly uses std::allocator<T>::construct to write into uninitialized memory. However, I am a bit confused about above case where I pass pointer to start of uninitialized memory.
As a follow up, if instead of make_unique_for_overwrite, I allocate the buffer using new std::byte[size] to avoid initializing data:
auto buffer = std::unique_ptr<T[]>(reinterpret_cast<T *>(new std::byte[data.size() * sizeof(T)]));

std::ranges::transform(data, buffer.get(), some_operation);

Is the code still valid, or is it undefined behavior? Maybe the code is okay if T is a trivial type.
I tried running example code with different sanitizers (undefined, memory, address), but none of them found any issues in the code. The compilers seem to do the right thing here, but I am not sure if the code is actually compliant with C++ standard.

The second one isn't valid because you're not guaranteed alignment.

The proper algorithm is uninitialized_copy. std::ranges::uninitialized_copy(data | std::views::transform(std::bind_front(std::multiplies<>{}, 2)), std::views::counted(buf.get(), size(data)));
